# What are the non-rating based recommendation systems

Tags: recommendation-engine

What are the non-rating based recommendation systems?

I could have used Recommenderlab but it needs a rating matrix as a input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for recommender system packages which can handle purchase data i would recommend take a look at https://github.com/benfred/implicit or at https://github.com/lyst/lightfm. Both packages can handle data sets with no explicit rating information (like for example 5 star movie ratings). Just google "implicit feedback recommender systems" which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data set is a boolean data set like; *userId, itemId* where rating doesn't exist.

Here is a solution with **Apache Mahout** for boolean data sets;

http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com.tr/2011/05/generating-recommendations-with-mahout_26.html